# Why read() wont return zero when reading from pipe

Tags: c, fork, pipe

I am having a problem with my assignment I have due for class.  I have to create a read/write program that will read a text file into it and write the contents to a new text file.  The thing is, I have to use parent/child processes and piping.  I have to pass the contents into the pipe with one child, and use another child to read the data from the pipe and write it to a new file.

I have three files: `parent.c`, `read.c` and `write.c`.  The program works fine for the most part!  It even transfers the data from one file to the other perfectly.  The problem I am having is that the write.c process will never complete.  I think it may have something to do with the reading from pipe(won't return 0 or EOF).  Here is my source code:

#### parent.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 255

int main(int ac, char* av[]) 
{   
    if(ac <3)
    {
        printf("Please enter all required arguments!\n");   
        exit(0);    
    }
    
    int pfd[2];
    int pipeCreated;
    
    char readFile[50];
    char writePipe[20];
    
    pid_t child_pid_read;
    pid_t child_pid_write;
    
    pipeCreated = pipe(pfd);
    
    if(pipeCreated == -1)
    {
        printf("An error occurred when trying to create a pipe\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    strcpy(readFile, av[1]);
    sprintf(writePipe,"%d", pfd[1]);
    
    child_pid_read = fork();
    
    char writeFile[50];
    char readPipe[20];
    
    //Handling the read()
    switch(child_pid_read) 
    {
        //Error in case forfk() failed
        case -1:
            perror("fork failed");
            return 1;
            
            //Handle child processes
        case 0:
             if(close(pfd[0]) == -1)
             {
                 printf("An error occurred while closing the pipe\n");
                 exit(0);
             }
             if(execle("./read.out", "./read.out", readFile, writePipe, (char*)0, NULL) == -1)
             {
                 printf("Child: Error creating read.\n");
                 exit(0);
             }
        
        default:
            wait(&child_pid_read);
            
            strcpy(writeFile, av[2]);
            sprintf(readPipe,"%d", pfd[0]);
             
            child_pid_write = fork();
            break;
    }
    
    //Handling the write
    switch(child_pid_write) 
    {
        //Error in case fork() failed
        case -1:
            perror("fork failed");
            return 1;
            
        //Handle child processes
        case 0:
            if(close(pfd[1]) == -1)
            {
                printf("An error occurred while closing the pipe\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            
            if(execle("./write.out", "./write.out", writeFile, readPipe, (char*)0, NULL) == -1)
            {
                printf("Child: Error creating read.\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
            break;
        
        default:
            wait(&child_pid_write);
            break;
    }
    printf("Write completed!");
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### read.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 16

int main(int ac, char* av[]) 
{   
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
    int fd;
    int pid;
    
    if(ac > 1)
    {
        fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);
        if(fd == -1)
        {
            printf("error: Could Not Open File\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        
        pid = atoi(av[2]);
        
    }
    
    int num_read = 1;
    
    while(1)
    {
        num_read = read(fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
        
        if(num_read == -1)
        {
            printf("Error reading file\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        
        if(num_read == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
                
        if(write(pid, buffer, num_read) != num_read)
        {
            printf("Error writing to pipe\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    return 1;
}
```

---

#### write.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 1

int main(int ac, char* av[]) 
{
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];

        int fd = open(av[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        
        int pid = atoi(av[2]);
        
        int num_read = 1;
    
    while(1)
    {
            num_read = read(pid, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
            
            printf("num_read: %d\n", num_read);
            
            if(num_read == -1)
            {
                printf("Error reading pipe\n");
                break;
            }
            
            if(write(fd, buffer, num_read) != num_read)
            {
                printf("Error writing to file\n");
                break;
            }
            
            if(num_read == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
    }
        
        close(fd);
        return 1;
}
```

---

Please look over my code and suggest corrections.  I am passing in the names of the text files through the terminal (`./parent.out`, `oldFile.txt`, `newFile.txt`).

Comment: For future reference, please read http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You're not forking the write process until after wait() for the read process returns. If the read process tries to write more data than will fit in the pipe buffer, it will block and never exit. You need to allow both processes to run concurrently to avoid this deadlock. It will work with a small file, but if the file is bigger than 4KB it will hang.
2. After forking the write process, the parent process has to close `pfd[0]`. The reader of a pipe doesn't get EOF until all processes that have the write end open close it. It should be:

   ```
   default:
       if(close(pfd[0]) == -1)
        {
            printf("An error occurred while closing the pipe\n");
            exit(0);
        }
       wait(&child_pid_write);
       break;
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This fixed my program and it works perfectly without hanging in read()!  You just saved me b/c this assignment was due tonight, and I had been working on it since Monday.  But again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your child want to read data,why you close the fd[0], return from pipe indicating that fd[0] for reading and fd[1] for writing.As i can't add a comment, i have to post the comment here....

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I didn't understand your post until Barmar posted his answer, but thanks in the same!